# Apache not killing threads for more than 20 minutes after reaching max thread number

Tags: mysql, multithreading, apache2

I am running a Linux server with 2 Xeon Quad core, with RAID10 and 8Gb of RAM.
I serve some products that dont use to overload the server, but 3 o 4 times a month, for the nature of the products, I get a huge amount of clients conecting to it.
For example, I got 1.000.000 requests in a lapse time of 3 hours.
The server has 2Gb asigned to the MySQL an Apache2 limited to 1500 threads using mpm.
The problem is that when the server reaches max number of threads (server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting) the load avg of the server gets really high, it goes from around 15 to 400 or so, and even after the clientes stops accessing, the number of apache threads keep really high and it may take more than 20 minutes to reducen de humber of them. By doing a 'ps aux' I can see that the process are created a the same time that the server reached the max number of threads.
If I do a strace of any of them I, it is doing just nothing.
The MSQL have no pending querys.

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    ServerLimit         2000
    #ListenBacklog      2000 #have just commented this out
    #MaxClients          150
    MaxClients          1500
    #MaxRequestsPerChild   0
    MaxRequestsPerChild   10000 # have just setted this value
</IfModule>
```

How can I prevent this from happening? Why are that threads no dieing or finishing?

I am expecting 1.000.000 hits today again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have reduced the number of MaxClients to 700 because 1500 is too much for 8Gb of RAM, each one may use 10 or more megas, so 700 is already a high number.

Comment: I think that the rate at what the thread of apaches die it is releated to a slowly kill just in case the load goes high again so it dont have to respawn all the threads again in a shot period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Apache has the option KeepAliveTimeout  that specify how many second to wait for a request before closing the connection. This require the option KeepAlive to be set to On.

There is also an option Timeout  that specify the max number of second to wait for a GET, POST, PUT request

Probably you must experiment with these option until you find the best balance for your work load and you application. Probably a good solution can be a KeepAlive On with a low Timeout and KeepAliveTimeout value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I was using this config

`Timeout 300 /
KeepAlive On /
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100 /
KeepAliveTimeout 15`

But the threads live for more than 20 minutes and they die at a rate of 1 per second. I have just turned the KeepAlive off and rised the number of

`MaxSpareServers 100`

Any other thoughts? Thanks